# Wordpress REST API Search decoded URL with cyrillyc symbols

Tags: search, rest-api

I'm trying to use REST API search opportunity with string:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=searchquerry,
```

but it doesn't works with decoded url and cyrillyc symbols.

For example, if I use url_decode and pass the string:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80
```

It doesn't work.

Can somebody help me with this? How I can use search in REST API with decoded URLs and cyrillic symbols?

For example, if I try to search:

```
https://traderblog.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?=search=adr
```

It works and I get search results with 'adr' keyword.

But when I try to get cyrillic search request:

```
https://traderblog.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80
```

It return wrong search results for %D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80 request.

Comment: use `url_decode` & `url_encode`

Comment: I use, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can i have your full code?

Comment: I added code to the question.